# Ordenas datos con pandas en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

espero que esten bien. Estoy haciendo un programa para gestionar empleados en python. La "base de datos" esta hecha en un csv que manipulo mediante la libreria pandas. A continuacion adjunto el codigo:

```
if num == 6:
    print(
        '\n 1) Buscar experiencia del empleado por el nombre'
        ' \n 2) Buscar experiencia del empleado por el apellido \n'
    )
    num = int(input('Ingrese la forma de busqueda que desea realizar: '))
    if num == 1:
        df = pd.read_csv('planeamiento3.csv', index_col='experiencia')
        experiencia = df # ['nombre']
        Nombreingresado = str(input('\nIngrese el nombre del empleado: '))
        Nombreingresado = Nombreingresado.lower()
        dato = experiencia[experiencia.nombre == Nombreingresado]
        print(dato[['nombre', 'apellido']])
```

Mi objetivo es lograr que el usuario pueda buscar la experiencia del empleado segun su nombre o apellido. Por ejemplo: introduzco el nombre javier y me devuelve 4 (años de experiencia). Pero ademas quiero que cuando devuelva la cantidad de años de experiencia del empleado, muestre su nombre, su apellido y obviamente su experiencia.
El csv tiene las siguientes columnas: nombre,apellido,edad,hijos,escuelahijos,antiguedad,estudiospropios,experiencia,sueldo,obrasocial
Y como fila tiene una que se llama numero (identifica el numero del empleado).
Por lo que el programa deberia buscar el nombre ingresado en la columna nombre y si existe, buscar los años de experiencia de ese empleado. Y finalmente imprimir su nombre, su apellido y sus años de experiencia.
Espero haber sido claro en la explicacion, cualquier consulta sobre mi codigo, puedo adjuntar mas codigo. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: podrias copiar y pegar el csv?, ya que como lo muestras no se entiende bien y no es apto para hacer pruebas

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es fácil, pues se soluciona aplicando un filtro, no entendí muy bien lo de la fila numero (aun que debería ser la columna), además al leer el archivo le indicas como índice de columna los años de experiencia, lo cual no debe ser así, suponiendo que tu `.csv` sea asi:

```
      nombre   apellido  edad  hijos escuelahijos  antiguedad estudiospropios  experiencia  sueldo obrasocial
0  christian  velasquez    16      0         nose           3     programador            3       0        nose
1       jose    alberto    20    100         nose           5       diseñador            1       0        nose
```

Podemos hacer esto:

```py
#leemos correctamente el archivo
df = pd.read_csv('planeamiento3.csv')

#convertimos a DF
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

#el nombre por el que va a buscar, esto puede ser el resultado de un input()
nombre = 'christian'

#aplicamos el filtro
res = df[df['nombre'] == nombre].loc[0] #obtenemos el primer resultado

#datos
nombre = res['nombre']
apellido = res['apellido']
edad = res['edad']
experiencia = res['experiencia']

#imprimimos la información
informacion = f"El trabador {nombre} {apellido} tiene {edad} años y {experiencia} años de experiencia"
print(informacion)
```

**Salida**

```
El trabador christian velasquez tiene 16 años y 3 años de experiencia
```

Por lo que veo tu código hace múltiples búsquedas, según por cada categoría (nombre, experiencia, apellido, etc), por lo que podemos hacerlo mas eficiente. Primero vamos a elaborar una estructura para las opciones (en este caso como diccionarios), luego abrimos el archivo, independientemente de la búsqueda que haga finalmente aplicaríamos el filtro

```py
#estructura de opciones de busqueda
opciones = {"1":"nombre","2":"apellido","3":"edad"}

#pedimos la opcion de busqueda
opcion = input("ingrese la opcion ")

#verificamos si la opcion existe
if opcion in opciones:
    campo= opciones[opcion]

#leemos correctamente el archivo
df = pd.read_csv('planeamiento3.csv')

#convertimos a DF
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

#realizamos la busqueda
busqueda = 'christian' #esto puede venir de un input 

#realizamos la busqueda segun el campo y que cumpla con el criterio de busqueda
res = df[df[campo] == busqueda].loc[0] #obtenemos el primer resultado

#obtenemos los datos
#datos
nombre = res['nombre']
apellido = res['apellido']
edad = res['edad']
experiencia = res['experiencia']

#imprimimos la informacion
informacion = f"El trabador {nombre} {apellido} tiene {edad} años y {experiencia} años de experiencia"
print(informacion)
```